# How to solve materialedittext rendering

Tags: android, xml

```
<com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/password"
android:text=""
android:inputType="textPassword"
android:textSize="34sp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
app:met_baseColor="@android:color/black"
app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
app:met_maxCharacters="20"
app:met_primaryColor="@color/md_red_500"
app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
android:id="@+id/R_password_edittext" />
```

When I use `MaterialEditText` library show me this problem

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Tip: Use `View.isInEditMode()` in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.AssertionError

Comment: I assume you mean in the layout editor?

You can ignore this, it just means that it won't render whilst using the editor. Should work fine once compiled.

Comment: But it needs when each update that closed it in the preview

Answer (score 0):

If you see this message in the layout editor preview, just ignore it. Or, alternatively change to a theme/style which will show it correctly.

[See image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLFDO.png)